# Many extra spaces in front of value after accepting a number in oracle sql

Tags: oracle11g

I am trying to accept a number, but after accepting it there is so much extra space in front of the `v_no`, is there any way to remove or prevent it?

Problem:

```
Enter value of 'N' for top 'N' of customer: 10
old 543:        ROWNUM <= &v_no
new 543:        ROWNUM <=         10 --there are so much space in front the 10
```

Here is my query:

```
ACCEPT v_no NUMBER FORMAT '99' PROMPT 'Enter value of ''N'' for top ''N'' of customer: '

ttitle center 'Top &v_no Valuable Customer' skip 2
SELECT
       ROWNUM "No."
     , "Customer ID"
     , "Customer Name"
     , "Customer Birthdate"
FROM
       (
                SELECT
                         row_number() OVER (ORDER BY c.cust_name) "No."
                       , c.cust_id "Customer ID"
                       , c.cust_name "Customer Name"
                       , c.cust_birthdate "Customer Birthdate"
                FROM
                         customer        c
                       , reservation     r
                WHERE
                         c.cust_id            = r.cust_id
                GROUP BY
                         c.cust_name
                       , c.cust_id
                       , c.cust_birthdate
                ORDER BY
                         1 DESC
       )
WHERE
       ROWNUM <= &v_no
;
```

Here is the output:

```
Enter value of 'N' for top 'N' of customer: 10
old 543:        ROWNUM <= &v_no
new 543:        ROWNUM <=         10

                                            Top         10 Valuable Customer

  No. Customer Customer               Customer  
      ID       Name                   Birthdate 
----- -------- ---------------------- ----------
    1 C0395    Chance Tomei           01/01/1972
    2 C0383    Aron Boatman           23/04/1972
    3 C0389    Andrew Mechi           31/07/1959
    4 C0371    Alisun Iacoviello      27/02/1997
    5 C0377    Pearl Bairnsfather     30/03/1988
    6 C0365    Adoree Standbridge     13/07/1995
    7 C0353    Swen Kift              23/05/1983
    8 C0359    Donella Whitcher       04/03/1974
    9 C0293    Gordon Perri           22/07/1977
   10 C0290    Hetti Treeby           01/08/1968
```

The space in front of the `v_no` making the title very ugly.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use TRIM() function, You can also use replace (v_no, ' ', '')

Comment: Use TRIM(&v_no) or REPLACE(v_no, ' ','') with condition ROWNUM <= TRIM(&v_no)

Comment: @Prathyush - you can't use `trim(&v_no)` directly in `ttitle`, it'll appear as `Top trim(10) Valuable Customer`. You *could* use `new_value` to assign the string value to a new variable, but it isn't necessary. And why use it in the `rownum` filter, so the `new` line looks better? That will also show `trim(10)`, which is equally odd, and now you're comparing a number to a string....

Comment: @AlexPoole, yeah you are right...i missed it. Thank you for pointing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`ttitle` command](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve048.htm) has a `format` option:

> FORMAT *text*
>
> Specifies a format model that determines the format of following data items, up to the next FORMAT clause or the end of the command. The format model must be a text constant such as A10 or $999. See the COLUMN command for more information on formatting and valid format models.

You can change your `ttile` line to use the same format as your `accept`, pulling the substitution variable out of the main string and specifying the format with:

```
ttitle center 'Top ' &v_no format 99 ' Valuable Customer' skip 2
```

Then when passed `10` the output is:

```
                        Top 10 Valuable Customer
```

and when passed say 2 the output is:

```
                         Top 2 Valuable Customer
```

Incidentally, you might want to add `set verify off` at the start of the script, which will stop it showing the `old` and `new` output - that still has the extra spaces anyway, but you probably don't want to see that in your final output anyway.

Comment: Thank you for that extra info, I'll make use of it.